# Не сохраняются файлы в ImageUploadBehavior

Tags: yii

Проблема с ImageUploadBehavior от [yii-dream-team/yii2-upload-behavior](https://github.com/yii-dream-team/yii2-upload-behavior).

Файл изображения не сохраняется в директорию.

- При этом имя файла верно считывается и записывается в базу. Например: 15783295728133.jpg
- Файл попадает в массив $_FILES
- Думал проблема алиасов, пробовал: `@app, @backend, @frontend`, etc. - не помогло
- Права на папке: 755
- Версия Yii2: 2.0.32

Код конфигурации:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => '\yiidreamteam\upload\ImageUploadBehavior',
            'attribute' => 'miniature',
            'filePath' => '@backend/web/storage/[[pk]].[[extension]]',
            'fileUrl' => '/storage/[[pk]].[[extension]]',
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Загрузка в переменную Поведения делалась путем события beforeValidate(). Поскольку у меня все данные валидируются в форме и на сущность попадают уже готовые к работе - валидация была отключена, как следствие - событие не отрабатывало.